# How can I group a dataframe based on string values without having to input literal string values?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe

```
structure(list(ID = c("45d67", "45d67", "45d67", "45d67"), Start = structure(c(1688933400, 
1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400), tzone = "America/New_York", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Book = c("Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle"
), Home = c("Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona"), Away = c("Pittsburgh", 
"Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh"), Team = c("Arizona", 
"Arizona", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh"), Points = c(3, -3, -3, 
3), American = c(-597L, 495L, 395L, -798L), Decimal = c(1.16750418760469, 
5.95, 4.95, 1.12531328320802)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 4 × 9
ID    Start               Book     Home    Away       Team       Points American Decimal
<chr> <dttm>              <chr>    <chr>   <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>    <int>   <dbl>
1 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Arizona         3     -597    1.17
2 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Arizona        -3      495    5.95
3 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Pittsburgh     -3      395    4.95
4 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Pittsburgh      3     -798    1.13
```

I have a calculation that needs to run but it requires grouping based on a Team and Points value.
Each grouping requires one of each team as well as a negative Points value and it's absolute value.  The desired groupings are as follows (Pay close attention to the Team and Points columns):

First Grouping

```
ID    Start               Book     Home    Away       Team       Points American Decimal
<chr> <dttm>              <chr>    <chr>   <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>    <int>   <dbl>
1 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Arizona         3     -597    1.17 
3 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Pittsburgh     -3      395    4.95
```

Second Grouping

```
ID    Start               Book     Home    Away       Team       Points American Decimal
<chr> <dttm>              <chr>    <chr>   <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>    <int>   <dbl>
2 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Arizona        -3      495    5.95 
4 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Pittsburgh      3     -798    1.13
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically where I don't have to specify literal string values?  I could very well have 25 different games with 50 different teams so inputting actual string values wouldn't work.

I have tried the following

```
df %>%
    arrange(ID, abs(Points)) %>% 
    mutate(rn = ceiling(row_number()/2)) %>%
    group_split(ID, rn)
```

however the Team column isn't grouped correctly as shown below.

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 10
ID    Start               Book     Home    Away       Team    Points American Decimal    rn
<chr> <dttm>              <chr>    <chr>   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>    <int>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Arizona      3     -597    1.17     1
2 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Arizona     -3      495    5.95     1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 10
ID    Start               Book     Home    Away       Team       Points American Decimal    rn
<chr> <dttm>              <chr>    <chr>   <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>    <int>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Pittsburgh     -3      395    4.95     2
2 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona Pittsburgh Pittsburgh      3     -798    1.13     2
```

Any help and/or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Updated Dataframe with additional ID, Teams and Points

```
structure(list(ID = c("695dd", "695dd", "695dd", "695dd", "695dd", 
"695dd", "695dd", "695dd", "695dd", "695dd", "45d67", "45d67", 
"45d67", "45d67", "45d67", "45d67", "45d67", "45d67", "45d67", 
"45d67", "45d67", "45d67", "45d67", "45d67", "45d67", "45d67"
), Start = structure(c(1688933100, 1688933100, 1688933100, 1688933100, 
1688933100, 1688933100, 1688933100, 1688933100, 1688933100, 1688933100, 
1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400, 
1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400, 
1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400, 1688933400), tzone = 
"America/New_York", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Book = c("Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", 
"Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", 
"Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", 
"Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", 
"Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle", "Pinnacle"), Home = c("San Fran", 
"San Fran", "San Fran", "San Fran", "San Fran", "San Fran", "San Fran", 
"San Fran", "San Fran", "San Fran", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", 
"Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", 
"Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", 
"Arizona"), Away = c("Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", 
"Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", 
"Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", 
"Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", 
"Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", 
"Pittsburgh"), Team = c("Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", 
"Colorado", "San Fran", "San Fran", "San Fran", "San Fran", "San Fran", 
"Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", 
"Arizona", "Arizona", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", 
"Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh"
), Points = c(-1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 1.5, -2, -2.5, -3, -3.5, 
3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, -1.5, -2, -2.5, -3, -3.5, -3, -2.5, -2, 1.5, 
2, 2.5, 3), American = c(439L, -133L, -175L, -253L, -306L, -711L, 
103L, 133L, 185L, 218L, -678L, -597L, -360L, -297L, 211L, 302L, 
336L, 495L, 437L, 395L, 264L, 226L, -275L, -422L, -488L, -798L
), Decimal = c(5.39, 1.75187969924812, 1.57142857142857, 
1.39525691699605, 
1.32679738562091, 1.14064697609001, 2.03, 2.33, 2.85, 3.18, 
1.14749262536873, 
1.16750418760469, 1.27777777777778, 1.33670033670034, 3.11, 4.02, 
4.36, 5.95, 5.37, 4.95, 3.64, 3.26, 1.36363636363636, 1.23696682464455, 
1.20491803278689, 1.12531328320802)), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = 
c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The grouping should like this.  Notice that there is a new ID which should also be grouped.

```
ID    Start               Book     Home     Away       Team       Points 
American Decimal
<chr> <dttm>              <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>    
<int>   <dbl>
1 695dd 2023-07-09 16:05:00 Pinnacle San Fran Colorado   Colorado     
-1.5      439    5.39
6 695dd 2023-07-09 16:05:00 Pinnacle San Fran Colorado   San Fran      
1.5     -711    1.14

2 695dd 2023-07-09 16:05:00 Pinnacle San Fran Colorado   Colorado      2       
-133    1.75
7 695dd 2023-07-09 16:05:00 Pinnacle San Fran Colorado   San Fran     -2        
103    2.03

3 695dd 2023-07-09 16:05:00 Pinnacle San Fran Colorado   Colorado      
2.5     -175    1.57
8 695dd 2023-07-09 16:05:00 Pinnacle San Fran Colorado   San Fran     
-2.5      133    2.33

4 695dd 2023-07-09 16:05:00 Pinnacle San Fran Colorado   Colorado      3       
-253    1.40
9 695dd 2023-07-09 16:05:00 Pinnacle San Fran Colorado   San Fran     -3        
185    2.85

5 695dd 2023-07-09 16:05:00 Pinnacle San Fran Colorado   Colorado      
3.5     -306    1.33
10 695dd 2023-07-09 16:05:00 Pinnacle San Fran Colorado   San Fran    
-3.5      218    3.18




11 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Arizona       
3.5     -678    1.15
19 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Pittsburgh   
-3.5      437    5.37

12 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Arizona       
3       -597    1.17
20 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Pittsburgh   
-3        395    4.95

13 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Arizona       
2.5     -360    1.28
21 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Pittsburgh   
-2.5      264    3.64

14 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Arizona       
2       -297    1.34
22 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Pittsburgh   
-2        226    3.26

15 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Arizona      
-1.5      211    3.11
23 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Pittsburgh    
1.5     -275    1.36

16 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Arizona      
-2        302    4.02
24 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Pittsburgh    
2       -422    1.24

17 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Arizona      
-2.5      336    4.36
25 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Pittsburgh    
2.5     -488    1.20

18 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Arizona      
-3        495    5.95
26 45d67 2023-07-09 16:10:00 Pinnacle Arizona  Pittsburgh Pittsburgh    
3       -798    1.13
```

Comment: try `split(mutate(df, rn = row_number(), .by = Team), ~rn)`

Comment: Hi @Onyambu I have updated my original post with an updated dataframe.  The new DF contains an additional ID, Teams and Points.  Your suggestion worked with the original post but I probably should have added the additional values to simulate the real world.  I need to be able to group on ID as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to split the data, although to make sure that the grouping is correct, you use `group_split` to check them out:

```
df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number(abs(Points)), .by = c(ID, Team))%>%
  group_by(ID, rn) %>%
  group_split()
```

Comment: The functionality in R never ceases to amaze me.  It's people like you that help to unlock it's true power!  Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
library(dplyr)

groups <- 
  df |>
  arrange(ID, abs(Points)) |>
  group_split(ID, row_number() %% 2)
```

control:

```
groups |>
  Map(f = \(df) df |> select(Team, Points, American))
```

output:

```
+ [[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Team       Points American
  <chr>       <dbl>    <int>
1 Arizona        -3      495
2 Pittsburgh      3     -798

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Team       Points American
  <chr>       <dbl>    <int>
1 Arizona         3     -597
2 Pittsburgh     -3      395
```

Comment: Hi @I_O, I have updated my original post with an updated dataframe.  The new DF contains an additional ID, Teams and Points.  Your suggestion worked with the original post but I probably should have added the additional values to simulate the real world.  I need to be able to group on ID as well.